# Rails 3: Different views for each model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have two models using Devise and I want the views to be different from one another. However, it only has one new.html.erb view, etc.

How can I have separate views for each model?

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If i am reading you correctly, assuming that you created a `User` model and, say, a `Admin` model, you'll want to do what is known as set devise up for Scoped Views.

You can generate the views for each model by calling `rails generate devise:views users`.

Then set `config.scoped_views = true` inside "*config/initializers/devise.rb*".

All of this is in the README as an fyi.